# How to use EF .SqlQuery expression in EFCore?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm refactoring a code and I have this question.

```
public class MovimentoManualListRepository : RepositoryBase<MovimentoManualList>, IMovimentoManualListRepository
{
    ConsultarContext _context;
    public MovimentoManualListRepository(ConsultarContext context) : base(context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public List<MovimentoManualList> Listar()
    {
        return _context.Database
            .SqlQuery<MovimentoManualList>("ListarMovimentacao")
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

I get an error:

> Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error CS1061 'DatabaseFacade' does not contain a definition for 'SqlQuery' and no accessible extension method 'SqlQuery' accepting a first argument of type 'DatabaseFacade' 
>   could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean [`FromSqlRaw`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql).?

> Basic raw SQL queries
>
> You can use the `FromSqlRaw` extension method to begin a LINQ query based on > a raw SQL query. `FromSqlRaw` can only be used on query roots, that is directly on the `DbSet<>`.
>
> ```
> var blogs = context.Blogs
>    .FromSqlRaw("SELECT * FROM dbo.Blogs")
>    .ToList();
> ```

The following executes a stored procedure

```
var blogs = context.Blogs
    .FromSqlRaw("EXECUTE dbo.GetMostPopularBlogs")
    .ToList();
```

Please note that:

- it can be mixed and matched it with Linq queries
- there are limitations

Please see [Raw SQL Queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql).

Comment: Can EFCore run raw Query useing context.Database? So we can select query  with return data type c# maybe dateTime, or string or int, or Guid?

Comment: Yes, with `context.Database.SqlQuery`, please see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/sql-queries#querying-scalar-non-entity-types

Comment: oke thanks This feature was introduced in EF Core 7.0.
My EF Version is v5.0.17 which is that feature is still not available yet at my EF version

Comment: You probably know this but EF Core is 'End of life'. Are you running on Core 3.1?

Comment: .NET Core 5. Yes this is out of support but we still use this version

Comment: Do you mean .NET 5 or EF Core 5? I understand that this depends on your team's circumstances but you may consider upgrading from .NET5 to .NET6 which supports EF Core 7.

Comment: Ok I know this .NET 6 is LTS and promising enough. but our company still use VS 2019. We do not have license for vs2022. We can use VS Code but another developer maybe have difficulties when changing to VS Code. 

There are some big projects here, and taking so much time, if converting that to new .NET version. maybe later when we need new app we will use .net 6